# C Program, Enter multiple numerical values via keyboard to use in program equation

Tags: c

This is probably a simple fix, but I am just pulling my hair out over this.

I need my output to look like this, but I cant figure out how to enter a value at the keyboard for use in the equation to calculate the Frostbite time and windchill. Please help I am new to programming.

```c
/* Preprocessor directives */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 /* Main function */
 int main(void)
 {
   /* Declare and initialize identifiers */
   double windchill,frostbitetime,airtemp,windspeed;

  /* Declare and initialize identifiers */         

   /* Compute windchill */
   windchill = 35.74+(.6215* airtemp)-(35.75*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)))+
               (0.4275*airtemp*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)));

   /* Compute frostbitetime */
   frostbitetime = (((-24.5*(0.667*windspeed*(1.6)))+4.8)+2111.0)*
                   ((pow(-4.8-((airtemp-32.0)*(.5556)), -1.668)));

   /* Print airtemp, windspeed, windchill, and frostbitetime */
   printf("  012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n");
   printf("01***************************************************\n");
   printf("02    WIND CHILL & FROSTBITE CALCULATION PROGRAM\n");
   printf("03\n");
   printf("04Enter the air temperature (degrees F) :%d",airtemp);scanf("%d",&airtemp);
   printf("05Enter the wind speed (miles/hour) :%d",windspeed);scanf("%d",&windspeed);
   printf("06\n");
   printf("07\n");
   printf("08Results\n");
   printf("09Air temperature = %5.1f MPH\n10Wind speed      = %5.1f F\n"
          "11Wind chill      = %5.1f F\n12Frostbite time  = %5.1f minutes\n",
           airtemp,windspeed,windchill,frostbitetime);
   printf("13***************************************************\n");
   printf("14\n");
   printf("15\n");

   /* Exit the program */
   printf("16Press Enter to quit.\n");
   getchar();
   return 0;​
```

I should be able to enter the values for air temperature and wind speed, for instance an air temp of 5 and wind speed of 15, and get a result of -13.0 degrees wind chill and 33.3 minutes for frostbite time.

Comment: See `fgets()` for more info - or search for "string entry 'C'"

Comment: You calculate `windchill` and `frostbitetime` using `airtemp` and `windspeed`, but your user only input their values later.

Comment: This is clearly C, not C++. Is there a reason you tagged it as such?

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, you should use `cin >> selection;` to get the selection after the menu is printed.

Comment: Also look at passing command line arguments using `getopt_long` you could have a user pass airtemp and windspeed as program arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the calculations **after** you read the values.

Currently, you have this:

```
/* Compute windchill */
windchill = 35.74+(.6215* airtemp)-(35.75*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)))+
               (0.4275*airtemp*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)));

/* Compute frostbitetime */
frostbitetime = (((-24.5*(0.667*windspeed*(1.6)))+4.8)+2111.0)*
                   ((pow(-4.8-((airtemp-32.0)*(.5556)), -1.668)));

...
scanf("%d",&airtemp);
scanf("%d",&windspeed);
```

The problem is that you're using trash values to calculate your `windchill`and your `frostbitetime`. To make it work, put those calculation **after** the `scanf`s.

Another problem you have is the format type you're using on [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). From the manual:

> ### l
>
> > Indicates either that the conversion will be one of d, i, o,
> >                   u, x, X, or n and the next pointer is a pointer to a long int
> >                   or unsigned long int (rather than int), **or that the conversion
> >                   will be one of e, f, or g and the next pointer is a pointer to
> >                   double (rather than float)**.  Specifying two l characters is
> >                   equivalent to L.  If used with %c or %s, the corresponding
> >                   parameter is considered as a pointer to a wide character or
> >                   wide-character string respectively.

So, you need to change the `%d` to `%lf`. And your code will look like:

```
...
scanf("%lf",&airtemp);
scanf("%lf",&windspeed);

/* Compute windchill */
windchill = 35.74+(.6215* airtemp)-(35.75*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)))+
               (0.4275*airtemp*(pow(windspeed, 0.16)));

/* Compute frostbitetime */
frostbitetime = (((-24.5*(0.667*windspeed*(1.6)))+4.8)+2111.0)*
                   ((pow(-4.8-((airtemp-32.0)*(.5556)), -1.668)));
```